# Can you put a hyphen on top of an underscore?

Tags: unicode, character

I want a character with a hyphen/dash on top of an underscore.

Is there such a character?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the other way around by adding a combining character `U+0332 COMBINING LOW LINE` (alias: `NON-SPACING UNDERSCORE`) *after* a `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS` (or possibly `U+2013 EN DASH`) character:

```
-̲ <U+002D, U+0332>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes/Maybe.

See https://superuser.com/a/675743 which has some suggestions:

1. Use http://shapecatcher.com/ to draw and find a symbol and;
2. To use a [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) modifier.

Using the shape catcher, I found “ニ” (Katakana letter ni).

And combining “_” with [U+305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) resulted in “_̅”. The site http://jkorpela.fi/fui.html8 was used to enter the characters.